# Scrollable div inside div, grid layout problem

Tags: html, css, scroll

I'd like to make a certain div scrollable (orange, unknown height, possible more than viewport). The page contains a container which includes 3 children. The div I need scrollable is part of one of these 3 childs.
If I set `overflow: auto` to `.con` scroll works like a charm. But I don't need to scroll through the complete `.con`.
**`.b` should always be visible.**

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content, min-content, auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sub {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.con {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.a {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.b {
  background-color: orange;
  overflow: auto; /* doesn't work :( */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    def<br>
    efg
  </div>
  <div class="con">
    <div class="a">
      fixed position
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content, min-content, auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sub {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.con {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.a {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.b {
  background-color: orange;
  overflow-y: scroll; 
  height: 500px;
}
 <div class="container">
    <div class="head">
      abc
    </div>
    <div class="sub">
      def<br>
      efg
    </div>
    <div class="con">
      <div class="a">
        fixed position
      </div>
      <div class="b">
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123<br>
        123
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The height of `.b` is unknown, because it's a table and I don't know how many rows it will contain.

Comment: I don't know the height of `.b` as I mentioned before. `.b` could be 100px or 1000px depending on the rows inside of the table.

Comment: without height it is not possible to add scrollbar to .b div

Comment: But it is possible. I found a solution ;)!

Comment: oh that's great. please provide the code snippet for my ref.

Answer (score 0):

keep the scroll on `.con` and use `position:sticky` on `.a`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content, min-content, auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sub {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.con {
  border: 1px solid green;
  overflow: auto;
}

.a {
  background-color: yellow;
  position:sticky;
  top:0;
}

.b {
  background-color: orange;
}

* {
 box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="head">
    abc
  </div>
  <div class="sub">
    def<br>
    efg
  </div>
  <div class="con">
    <div class="a">
      fixed position
    </div>
    <div class="b">
      start<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      123<br>
      end
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.b` should always be visible.

Comment: @awdrt define *always visible*

Comment: My mistake, i meant `a`. If I scroll in the orange div, a should always be visible.

Comment: @awdrt that's why I am using position sticky. It's always visible unless you are using a browser that doesn't support sticky